# Grid with overlapping rows?

Tags: html, css, grid, rows, overlap

I'm creating a card game and I want to use a grid to position the cards (div's). How can I create a grid where the rows overlap like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bfiC.png)?

Comment: Those are 4 divs, with same position absolute and width the same, height different.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with floats. At least it works in all browsers.

HTML:

```
<div class="card-set">
  <div class="row row-1">
    <!-- 1st row -->
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-2">
    <!-- 2nd row -->
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-3">
    <!-- 3rd row -->
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-4">
    <!-- 4rd row -->
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-10">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
$grid-width: 1000px;
$gutter-horizontal: 15px;
$next-row-margin: 15px;
$card-height: 80px;
$card-gutter: 11px;
$row-number: row !default;

.row {
  max-width: $grid-width;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;

  // Clearfix
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  [class^="col-"] {
    float: left;

    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: $gutter-horizontal;
    }
  }
}

@for $i from 2 to 10 {
  .#{$row-number}-#{$i} {
    top: #{$card-gutter * $i};
    z-index: $i - 1;
  }
}

.col-1-of-10 {
  width: calc((100% - 9 * #{$gutter-horizontal})/10);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  height: $card-height;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/alac1984/pen/YzzmRJK?editors=1100

Comment: I'm sorry, but Stack Overflow is not an on demand code site. It's a plataform where programmers asks questions. Asking it that way seems like you don't intend to code anything, just want a final solution for what you need. You should be capable of adapt this code for your needs.

Comment: What are you talking about? I've spent like 20 hours writing and rewriting my code. I started with the CSS Grid Layout Module but found out that I couldn't offset the rows so I had to make my own grid. "You should be capable of adapt this code for your needs". What do you know about my capabilities? What's the minimum knowledge level for being allowed to ask a question?