# Animating a div to another div's position and follow it when resizing screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-grid

I'm creating a card game and at the start some cards should be dealt - they should travel from the deck to certain "dropZonePositions" on the board. I've made an animation for this which I'm pleased with. The problem is that the cards don't align with the "dropZonePositions" when the user resizes the screen.

The positions of these dropZonePositions are being calculated with the CSS Grid Layout Module and adjusts to screen resizing. The cards, however, are being positioned by jQuery's `.animate()` which apperantly adds a style attribute with values for "top" and "left". These values does **not** adjust to screen resizing.

I've tried to append the card-div's to the dropZonePosition-div's after the animation but that doesn't work (maybe I need to change my CSS for that to work?). I've also tried to remove the style attribute after it's been added by `.animate()`. That doesn't work either.

**My question:**
How can I have cards align with their "dropZonePositions" when the screen is resized?

https://codepen.io/Rawland_Hustle/pen/MWWNPPe

```js
let deck =[
  {card: 1, value: 1, color: "hearts"},
  {card: 2, value: 2, color: "hearts"},
  {card: 3, value: 3, color: "hearts"},
  {card: 4, value: 4, color: "hearts"},
  {card: 5, value: 5, color: "hearts"},
  {card: 6, value: 1, color: "diamonds"},
  {card: 7, value: 2, color: "diamonds"},
  {card: 8, value: 3, color: "diamonds"},
  {card: 9, value: 4, color: "diamonds"},
  {card: 10, value: 5, color: "diamonds"},
  {card: 11, value: 1, color: "spades"},
  {card: 12, value: 2, color: "spades"},
  {card: 13, value: 3, color: "spades"},
  {card: 14, value: 4, color: "spades"},
  {card: 15, value: 5, color: "spades"},
  {card: 16, value: 1, color: "clubs"},
  {card: 17, value: 2, color: "clubs"},
  {card: 18, value: 3, color: "clubs"},
  {card: 19, value: 4, color: "clubs"},
  {card: 20, value: 5, color: "clubs"}  
]

function shuffleCards(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    
    return array;
  
}

let cards = shuffleCards(deck);

var deckZonePosition = $("#deckZone").offset();

$.each(cards, function() {
  $('<div />', {
    'class': "card",
    id: this.card,
    'text': this.value + " of " + this.color
  }).appendTo('#deckZone')
  .offset(deckZonePosition);
});

var dropZonePositions = [];

$('.dropzone[data-row="2"]').each(function(){
  dropZonePositions.push($(this).offset());
});


$(".card").each(function(index){
  
  var Left = dropZonePositions[index].left;
  var Top = dropZonePositions[index].top;
  
  $(this).delay(index * 50).animate({top: Top, left: Left});
  
  $(this).appendTo($('.dropzone[data-row="2"]')[index]);
    
  // Stannar loopen efter 10 varv
  return index < 9;
  
});
```

```css
#topCardContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#cardContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topRowDropzone {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: LightGray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
}

#deckZone {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: Black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
}

#emptyTopRowDropzone {
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
}

.dropzone {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
}

.card {
  background-color: LightGray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topCardContainer">
  <div id="deckZone" card=""></div>
  <div id="emptyTopRowDropzone" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_1" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_2" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_3" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_4" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_5" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_6" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_7" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_8" card=""></div>
</div>

<div id="cardContainer">
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_1" data-row="1" data-column="1" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_2" data-row="1" data-column="2" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_3" data-row="1" data-column="3" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_4" data-row="1" data-column="4" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_5" data-row="1" data-column="5" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_6" data-row="1" data-column="6" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_7" data-row="1" data-column="7" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_8" data-row="1" data-column="8" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_9" data-row="1" data-column="9" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_10" data-row="1" data-column="10" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_11" data-row="2" data-column="1" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_12" data-row="2" data-column="2" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_13"data-row="2" data-column="3" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_14" data-row="2" data-column="4" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_15" data-row="2" data-column="5" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_16" data-row="2" data-column="6" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_17" data-row="2" data-column="7" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_18" data-row="2" data-column="8" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_19" data-row="2" data-column="9" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_20" data-row="2" data-column="10" card=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add `jQuery(window).on("resize", function() {})` where you recalculate the position of dropzones and cards.

Comment: @Kalimah I'm not sure I understand. I'm not recalculating the positions myself. The CSS Grid Layout Module and my browser recalculate them automatically when the browser window is stretched or when the mobile device is tilted etc.

Comment: the elements are set using vw and vh unit. While animate set them using px unit. When the window is resized vw and vh are automatically calculated while px stays fixed

Comment: @Kalimah Thanks! I use `offset()` to get the positions of the "dropZonePositions" and then `jQuery(window).on("resize", function() {})` to reposition the cards to them.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not require a resize event. You can use animate callback function to perform certain action. I used to append the animated card inside the container, then set it's top and left to zero. Also, you need to set the parent container to relative to contain the cards.

See this example:

```js
let deck = [{
    card: 1,
    value: 1,
    color: "hearts"
  },
  {
    card: 2,
    value: 2,
    color: "hearts"
  },
  {
    card: 3,
    value: 3,
    color: "hearts"
  },
  {
    card: 4,
    value: 4,
    color: "hearts"
  },
  {
    card: 5,
    value: 5,
    color: "hearts"
  },
  {
    card: 6,
    value: 1,
    color: "diamonds"
  },
  {
    card: 7,
    value: 2,
    color: "diamonds"
  },
  {
    card: 8,
    value: 3,
    color: "diamonds"
  },
  {
    card: 9,
    value: 4,
    color: "diamonds"
  },
  {
    card: 10,
    value: 5,
    color: "diamonds"
  },
  {
    card: 11,
    value: 1,
    color: "spades"
  },
  {
    card: 12,
    value: 2,
    color: "spades"
  },
  {
    card: 13,
    value: 3,
    color: "spades"
  },
  {
    card: 14,
    value: 4,
    color: "spades"
  },
  {
    card: 15,
    value: 5,
    color: "spades"
  },
  {
    card: 16,
    value: 1,
    color: "clubs"
  },
  {
    card: 17,
    value: 2,
    color: "clubs"
  },
  {
    card: 18,
    value: 3,
    color: "clubs"
  },
  {
    card: 19,
    value: 4,
    color: "clubs"
  },
  {
    card: 20,
    value: 5,
    color: "clubs"
  }
]

function shuffleCards(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }

  return array;

}

let cards = shuffleCards(deck);

var deckZonePosition = $("#deckZone").offset();

$.each(cards, function() {
  $('<div />', {
      'class': "card",
      id: this.card,
      'text': this.value + " of " + this.color
    }).appendTo('#deckZone')
    .offset(deckZonePosition);
});

var dropZonePositions = [];

$('.dropzone[data-row="2"]').each(function() {
  dropZonePositions.push($(this).offset());
});


$(".card").each(function(index) {

  var Left = dropZonePositions[index].left;
  var Top = dropZonePositions[index].top;

  $(this).delay(index * 50).animate({
    top: Top,
    left: Left
  }, {
    complete: function() {
      $(this).css({top: "-3px", left: "-3px"}).appendTo($('.dropzone[data-row="2"]')[index]);
   $(this).parent().css("position", "relative");
    }
  });



  // Stannar loopen efter 10 varv
  return index < 9;

});
```

```css
#topCardContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#cardContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topRowDropzone {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: LightGray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
}

#deckZone {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: Black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
}

#emptyTopRowDropzone {
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
}

.dropzone {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
}

.card {
  background-color: LightGray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: calc(8vw * 1.55);
  width: 8vw;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topCardContainer">
  <div id="deckZone" card=""></div>
  <div id="emptyTopRowDropzone" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_1" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_2" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_3" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_4" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_5" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_6" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_7" card=""></div>
  <div class="topRowDropzone" id="topRowDropzone_8" card=""></div>
</div>

<div id="cardContainer">
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_1" data-row="1" data-column="1" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_2" data-row="1" data-column="2" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_3" data-row="1" data-column="3" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_4" data-row="1" data-column="4" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_5" data-row="1" data-column="5" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_6" data-row="1" data-column="6" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_7" data-row="1" data-column="7" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_8" data-row="1" data-column="8" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_9" data-row="1" data-column="9" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_10" data-row="1" data-column="10" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_11" data-row="2" data-column="1" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_12" data-row="2" data-column="2" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_13" data-row="2" data-column="3" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_14" data-row="2" data-column="4" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_15" data-row="2" data-column="5" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_16" data-row="2" data-column="6" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_17" data-row="2" data-column="7" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_18" data-row="2" data-column="8" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_19" data-row="2" data-column="9" card=""></div>
  <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone_20" data-row="2" data-column="10" card=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I like the solution `jQuery(window).on("resize", function() {})` better since I don't want to my CSS more complicated than it already is. I'm trying to make the rows overlap eachother but I don't know how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59094322/grid-with-overlapping-rows/59097891#59097891. If I add more CSS I'm totally lost.